# Why shared preferences aren't saving my variable on close?

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

When I restart the app or change activity my integer resets back to 0. On button click the value increases by 1.

I am also interested in where is Sharedpreferences files saved, because I can't find it in /data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/shared_prefs/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME_preferences.xml

```
class gumb extends State<MyHomePage>{
  int _counter = 0;
  _save() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final key = _counter.toString();
    final value = _counter;
    prefs.setInt(key, value);
    print('saved $value'+ key );

  }
  _read() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final key = _counter.toString();
    final value = prefs.getInt(key) ?? 0;
    print('read: $value');
    _counter = value;
  }
  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    _read();
    debugPrint("that's great");

  }
.
.
. 
void _incrementCounter(){
    setState(() {
      _read();

      _save();


    });
  }
.
.
.
void ajaj(){
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
...
//Code for button
child: FlatButton(
       padding: EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
       onPressed: (){
       _incrementCounter();
       ajaj();
...

//container where the counter shows up
Container(
              child: Text('$_counter',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red[500], fontSize: 32, fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                  fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                  fontFamily: 'Open Sans',
```

There aren't any errors on button click.

Comment: Hi @Maybe. You're using the same variable for both the key and the value. That doesn't seem right...

Comment: Your `key` should be a fixed string, for example: `savedCounter`

Comment: Thank you for your answer but that didn't exactly fix my problem, for some reason the `_counter` started to reset at 26. But I found another solution.

Answer (score 0):

I changed functions `_read` and `_save` into `_incrementCounter` and made another `_read`, which is used when the activity starts. I found the solution on https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

```
_incrementCounter() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    counter = (prefs.getInt('counter') ?? 0) + 1;
    print('Pressed $counter times.');
    await prefs.setInt('counter', counter);
  }
  _read() async {
    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    counter = (pref.getInt('counter')?? counter);
    print("Saved: $counter");
    setState(() {
      pref.setInt('counter', counter);
    });

  }
```